# Node / Express - Is there a way to access static files from a controller method?

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

Inside the controller method, is there a way to access static files? I am using mailgun to send emails and need to send an html file in my request that is located in /public.

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var html = getHtml(); // Need to get the html here to pass to mailgun
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a way to access the static file dir using some handy device provided by Express? No, not that I'm aware of.

Is there a way to get what you're trying to do done? Sure. Read it with the `fs` module. I like to use the `path` module, too, to generate my path to the file.

```
const path = require("path");
const fs   = require("fs");

// Do however you like to build paths. 
// I like to use resolve so I always get an absolute path.
const publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "public"); 

const htmlPath = path.join(publicPath, "thefile.html");

app.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile(htmlPath, "utf8", onFile);

  function onFile (err, html) {
    if (err) return next(err); // assuming you're using an error handler, like you probably should be
    mailgunThatStuff(html, mgDone);  
  }

  function mgDone (err) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     res.end("OK mailgun'd that thing");
  }
}
```

That's a little wordy, maybe. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

(app.js) you just mention static folder in app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

index.html page in local flower in ./public/pages/

```
app.all('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: './public/pages/'});
});
```

try this its working fine